# NetSuite purchase request approval through email

Tags: workflow, netsuite

When NetSuite sends a purchase request notification email to a designated approver, is it possible for that email to contain buttons that the approver would be able to use to approve/reject the request? Alternatively, is there another way to allow the approver to approve / reject the request through email without having to log into the system?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of. However, one potential solution would go something like this:

1. Build a Suitelet or RESTlet that performs the approval (RESTlet preferred).
2. Build a PHP page (or any server-side page in whatever language you want) that constructs the appropriate HTTP request for the RESTlet
3. Put a link to the PHP page in the email.

The user would simply see and click a link in the email, and the PHP/RESTlet would take care of the approval action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, approval or rejection is possible through email response.

You have to use `NetSuite` Email capture plug-in along with an workflow. In the mail sent to approver (from Workflow SendEmail action) have the following html snippet included in email body. In this example, subject included values to indicate Approval/Rejection, Transaction to act on, CurrentState of Workflow.

' &subject=Approve%20{tranid}%20FinanceApproval&body=">Click here to Approve '

`Emailcapture` plug-in user event gets triggered once the email is received. Event script can check the subject, perform validations and then perform necessary action on the workflow using `nlapiTriggerWorkflow`.

**Note:** 
1. Use workflowactionApprove, workflowflowactionReject as button id in all the states in the workflow, so that its easier to refer in the script. 
2. If additional comments needs to be captured during approval/rejection, mention in the mail sent to approver, to provide his comments in the body of the response mail.  Emailcapture plug-in event can parse the mail body and update necessary fields.

thanks,
Veda.
Skalable Technologies.

Comment: html code snippet got truncated.   You have to use an anchor tag in email body with href  value as:

"mailto:EmailCapturePluginMailID?<br>&amp;subject=Approve%20{tranid}%20FinanceApproval&amp;body="


thanks,
Veda.
Veda@skalabletech.com